# List Comprehension Leaving Out Values

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm having a little bit of trouble with my list comprehension code. Given an ordered list X of distinct ints and analogous list Y, construct the list of all pairs (x,y) such that x is from X, y from Y, and x < y. The resulting list must be ordered so that the pairs with the smaller x go first and among the pairs that have the same x, the ones with the smaller y go first (see examples in the test cases).

For example: input --> 3 4 5 6 7; 1 2 3 4 5
output:
3 4
3 5
4 5

```
Xstrs = input().split(' ')
X = [int(x) for x in Xstrs]

Ystrs = input().split(' ')
Y = [int(x) for x in Ystrs]

Z = [(x,y) for x in Xstrs for y in Ystrs  if x < y] #insert a list comprehension expression

for pair in Z: print(pair[0], pair[1])
```

---

The code above works perfectly accept for when I put in these set of lists:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8 9 10

In this case after the 1 combinations (ie. (1,4)(1,5) etc.) it always leaves out the combination with 10. For example: it leaves out (2,10) (3,10) and so forth. Could someone please explain to me why this might be happening?

Comment: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7     ---------------     4 5 6 7 8 9 10 8 *** these were meant to be 2 separate lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because you loop through Xstrs and Ystrs in your list comprehension and because these are strings, '2' is considered greater than '10'

Just change this line:

```
Z = [(x,y) for x in Xstrs for y in Ystrs  if x < y]
```

to this

```
Z = [(x,y) for x in X for y in Y  if x < y]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It did work, I really appreciate it. The explanation is good as well!